# Missing readline library or readline.h (Already tried other solutions)

Tags: make

I am trying to install an open source project [Rosie Pattern Language (RPL)](https://github.com/jamiejennings/rosie-pattern-language) via the make command. I am getting this error: `Missing readline library or readline.h`.
I have installed the required readline packages via `sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev` which did not resolve the issue.

Update:
Ubuntu Version: 16.04.3

Output of `dkpg -S readline.h`:

```
libreadline6-dev:amd64: /usr/include/readline/readline.h
```

Comment: Please update your question with your Ubuntu version and output of `dpkg -S readline.h`.

Comment: Which software do you trying to install?

Comment: https://github.com/jamiejennings/rosie-pattern-language

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to install corresponding packages with

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential libreadline-dev
```

Then clone repository and make:

```
git clone https://github.com/jamiejennings/rosie-pattern-language.git
cd rosie-pattern-language/
make
```

And run software with

```
./bin/rosie
```